# Late 90s book; similar to The Matrix, a guy is in a simulation he doesn't know isn't real

Tags: story-identification, books

The basic story is a wet wire VR simulation that ended up with some people getting killed because of the wet wire interface. The protagonist suffered from hallucinations and spent some time in a mental hospital and of course the project was abandoned.

Protagonist gets better. Goes on with his life. Years later he runs into a colleague from the project. Surprise! you are still in the simulation.

Bad guys want the technology but they don't know the physical location of the project but they can jack into the simulation and do bad guy stuff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The closest match I can think of is "Realtime Interrupt" by J. P. Hogan (matches the "encounters a colleague... surprise!" part, and there are bad guys, even if the physical location of the project is, if memory serves, well known).

Comment: Please don't list multiple options in 1 answer; it makes it very hard to consider it "correct."

Comment: DUDE! you got it. Real Time Interrupt!  Thanks so much!

Comment: Amended answer. I only left the very closest match. (Should anyone wonder, similar plots are e.g. in Ben Bova's Death Dream and Tad Williams' Otherland tetralogy)

Comment: you beat reddit. That is impressive.